# How to access services in a different kubernetes cluster using DNS

Tags: kubernetes

How to access services in a different kubernetes cluster using DNS and not willing to use External ingress.
With in the cluster I am using internal DNS ex: mysvc.mynamespace.
How i can achieve the same from one Cluster to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore [KubeFed](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed) which allows cross cluster [service discovery](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed/blob/master/docs/servicedns-with-externaldns.md)